# Chai spies not working on Browser

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to use chai spies with mocha running on browser, but something is not working.

With this html configuration:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/chai-spies/chai-spies.js"></script>

  <script>
    mocha.setup('bdd')
    mocha.reporter('html');
    var expect = chai.expect;
  </script>

  <script src="./test.js"></script>

  <script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('PhantomJS') < 0) {
      mocha.run();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this test file:

```
describe("test spies", function () {
    it("are worning", function () {
        function myFunction () {
          console.log("Hello");
        }
        var spy = chai.spy(myFunction);
        expect(spy).to.be.spy;
        myFunction();
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
    });
});
```

I get the following assertion error:

```
AssertionError: expected { Spy } to have been called
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/input-text-test-fixture.html:282:28)
```

Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: I'm working on chrome

Comment: Weird, the testing code seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the spy itself - not the function.

```
describe("test spies", function () {
it("are worning", function () {
    function myFunction () {
      console.log("Hello");
    }
    var spy = chai.spy(myFunction);
    expect(spy).to.be.spy;
    spy(); // Call the spy here
    expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
});
```

});

The spy wraps the function and internally calls it. By just calling the function itself you give `chai-spies` no chance in recording that the function actually has been called.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.